# Warning while validate ios app

Tags: ios

I just move to upload my first app.I am using xcode 7,swift app.while validating i got any message like this:

[image]

I also google it about this problem.In this stack over flow also I saw some solution that its just a warning.but when I move to iTunes to wait for that + button to build my app and to submit. I am not able to see that + button in iTunes.

I also delete my archive and re-archives and wait for one hour.till now I din see that + button to add my build 
Now what shall I do.Kindl give some soilution
Thanks in advance !

Updated:

here after validate one +button will shows to add.That only i din get

[image]

Comment: I get the same warning, after doing some research, this warning can indeed be safely ignored.

Comment: because these warning are showed after moved to swift 2.0. I also face these warning message .But could't solve it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***See the steps you followed or not :***

first of all create a new ios app and fill all details.Then move on to the steps: 
1. archive your app
2. validate it
3. submit to app store
4. then only you will see that + ( build) button over there.

If you already done these steps.Then also you not get means try to change build number or version and re do all steps.sure this will work.

Hope this help !

Comment: ohh yes i forgot to select submit to app store button.Thanks man.This is my first app submission so nly littlebit confused.

Answer (score 4):

This error won't affect your ability to upload the app to iTunes Connect.
Once you have opened iTunes Connect - go to My Apps -> Plus Icon -> New App. The just follow the steps and you should be good.

[image]

Comment: i finish all step .After validate we will move to itunes to see + button to add our archive.see my update post.ther i am not able to see plus + build button